# Perform animation by adding a class to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a menu which plays an animation on click (div with text flies in). When clicking another item in the menu the current div fades and the next one flies in.

I'm trying to do this by adding a class, `transorm transiracy`, and playing the animation. I've been trying for several hours now, yet nothing works. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('.link').onclick = function("myFunction");

function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("panel");
  element.classList.add("textcss");
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="#0">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link2" href="#0">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link3" href="#0">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="text">
  <div class="panel1" id='panel'>
    <p>PANEL1 <br><br></p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel2" id='panel'>
    <p>PANEL2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel3" id='panel'>
    <p>PANEL 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS class?

Comment: `id`s within the document are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Yeah what Teemu says. Your panels should have different IDs instead of all being called 'panel'.

Comment: Your JS is not correct: (1) you are working with a HTMLCollection: you need to iterate through it, (2) you should probably use `Element.addEventListener('click', myFunction)` instead. Moreover, your `panel` ID is repeated in the DOM, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanx! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit tricky, it will be very easy if you only want one effect, either fly or fade-out , but you need 2 of them, so you need to manipulate classes for fade-out and fly effect, **you can change the left and top potions to change your flying effect.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.link').click(function(){
            $('.link').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var realtion = $(this).data('relation');
            $('.text .panel').removeClass('active').addClass('stayHere');
            $('.text').find('#' + realtion).addClass('active').removeClass('stayHere');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.text .panel').removeClass('stayHere')
            },1000);
        });
        
    });
```

```css
.text {
        position: relative;
    }
    .link {cursor: pointer;}
    .text .panel {
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        transition: top 1s, left 1s, opacity 1s;
        top: -200px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .text .panel.active {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block !important;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .stayHere {
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        opacity: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" data-relation="panel1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" data-relation="panel2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" data-relation="panel3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="text">
  <div class="panel" id='panel1'>
    <p>PANEL1 <br><br></p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id='panel2'>
    <p>PANEL2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id='panel3'>
    <p>PANEL 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to mark it as right anser and upvote too

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: where the answer starts, on left side, there is a right tick in grey color, jut click that

Comment: Thax! Did it; it works fine. I'm now trying to add animations (animate.js) with the new generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/60uqp7jt/9/

JS - Jquery

```
let link = $('.link');
let panel = $('.panel');

link.click(function() {
    let dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    panel.hide();
    $('#'+ dataId).show();
});
```

CSS

```
.panel {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="#0" data-id="panel-1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#0" data-id="panel-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#0" data-id="panel-3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="text">
  <div class="panel" id="panel-1">
    <p>PANEL1 <br><br></p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-2">
    <p>PANEL2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-3">
    <p>PANEL 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```